# Installing node.js on CentOS 5

Tags: python, node.js, centos

I'm pretty new to CentOS (5) and also node.js, but I already got an older version of node.js to work on my virtual server. 
Now I'm trying to install a newer version, and I know that CentOS needs Python 2.4 while node needs 2.6 or newer, so I installed Python 2.7 using altinstall.

But even if I set an alias for Python that points to version 2.7 before running ./configure, I still get this error:

```
/root/node/wscript: error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/node/tools/wafadmin/Utils.py", line 274, in load_module
    exec(compile(code, file_path, 'exec'), module.__dict__)
  File "/root/node/wscript", line 222
    "-pre" if node_is_release == "0" else ""
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

That's the content of ./configure:

```
#! /bin/sh

# v8 doesn't like ccache
if [ ! -z "`echo $CC | grep ccache`" ]; then
  echo "Error: V8 doesn't like cache. Please set your CC env var to 'gcc'"
  echo "  (ba)sh: export CC=gcc"
  exit 1
fi

CUR_DIR=$PWD

#possible relative path
WORKINGDIR=`dirname $0`
cd "$WORKINGDIR"
#abs path
WORKINGDIR=`pwd`
cd "$CUR_DIR"

"${WORKINGDIR}/tools/waf-light" --jobs=1 configure $*

exit $?"
```

And at the top of wscript there is the following line: "#!/usr/bin/env python". I also tried replacing that with something else, though I think it should work when using a Python alias

Any ideas what I need to do to get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like `./configure` or perhaps `wscript` is still calling Python2.4 rather than Python2.7. Can you show us how `./configure` is calling `wscript`?

Comment: To be sure of the source of the problem, you could open `wscript` and stick `import sys` followed by `print sys.version` at the top, thus printing out the version of Python _actually_ being used for execution. (By the way, as you're discovering, CentOS/RHEL 5 is actually pretty old; moving to 6 could save you a lot of headaches.)

Comment: Thanks, Nicholas. Not sure about updating CentOS. As mentioned I'm far from being really familiar with it...

Answer (score 5):

I have python 2.7.3 'altinstalled' on Centos 5.x, with the binary named "/usr/local/bin/python2.7"

I compile and install nodejs v0.8.16 using:

```
PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python2.7
export PYTHON
python2.7 configure && make && make install
```

- running **configure** with python2.7 overrides the default python handling
- creating a PYTHON env var allows **make install** to find the correct version of python

(I still had to identify and install missing development modules one by one before the install would succeed)

Comment: This advice, along with [the install script linked here](http://rajaseelan.com/2012/01/28/installing-python-2-dot-7-2-on-centos-5-dot-2/) is pure gold; got py 2.7 installed and then got node.js installed! Double hooray!

Answer (score 1):

I changed the PATH in bash_profile to include the path to the desired version of python as follows:

vi ~/.bash_profile  
replace PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
with PATH=/usr/local/python272/bin:$PATH:$HOME/bin
source ~/.bash_profile
./configure
make

It picks up the correct python version. No need to change wscript

I'm on CentOS 5.6, python 2.7.2 (installed in /usr/local/python272) and using node.js 0.4.12

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same exact problem. I wound up editing the wscript file and changed that line (222) from this:

```
"-pre" if node_is_release == "0" else ""
```

...to this:

```
""
```